# Finding k for kmeans in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means, data-science

So I have a dataset consisting 130000 points, in the format (x,y). My final goal is to cluster this data using kmeans. But for applying that, I need to find the optimum number of clusters to pass to the kmeans algorithm. How should I apply something like Gap Statistics or Levene's test in python to achieve this?

Comment: check [this](https://gist.github.com/michiexile/5635273) example using scipy.